# Computed datetime for select - split or concatenate?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm designing the database layout for an app which will make heavy use of time-based queries. I'm trying to figure out which would be the optimal choice for DB layout. I control the insert/update process, but the data will be feeding back into various Excel spreadsheets, and the consumers will be varied enough that it's not really realistic to expect to be able to do much on the client side. Any of the fields could be used for either WHEREs or ORDER BYs. My options are:

1. A stored datetime field, and seperate calculated date / time fields
2. Stored time and date fields, and a calculated datetime field
3. No calculated fields - store all 3 fields seperately at INSERT/UPDATE time

It seems more sensible to calculate a field rather than duplicate data and risk inconsistencies, which leaves me to decide whether to split a datetime, or concatenate seperate fields to get the desired calculated field.

My gut tells me that concatenating should be more efficient than splitting, but is there really much in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 storing a datetime field and calculating date and time parts from that should be fine.

I would always prefer having less data stored physically.

If that computation is too complex however slowing you down you might consider making it a `PERSISTED COMPUTED COLUMN` which is in a way a compromise between Option 1 and Option 3.
(Except for that you do not have to insert it manually)

See Point 3 in this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917696.aspx) for more information on persisted computed columns.

Comment: Persisted computed sounds like EXACTLY what I'm after. Thanks for the fast reply!